# Creating simple CRUD frontend component in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-component

I am trying to convert a php application to joomla1.5 app. I have read some docs on how to create components in joomla1.5 but however i am lost at the best approach to create a simple CRUD frontend Component.

Here are my few questions

1) Should i perform my CRUD operations using JTable or simply use models and write my insert,update,select and delete scripts in the methods?
2) Where should this table class be placed if JTable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing before you get too far is to upgrade to 2.5. There is no point in developing anything for software that is reaching end of life in about 60 days.

Next, anything dealing with the database should be put in the model. In Joomla it should be pretty straight forward, have you ready the MVC tutorial? Start with that, it should clear things up.

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, forget Joomla 1.5 and then use [this scaffolding tool](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/)